# Amazon ECS with jmeter server can not connect on ip

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs, amazon-ecr

Created my own docker image for the Jmeter server instance. Tested this container locally and everything works well. I can connect using docker IP like 172.17.0.3 and run my tests.

I push this container into Amazon ECR and then create task on ECS. Container started well in ECS, and logs are good:

```
Created remote object: UnicastServerRef2 [liveRef: [endpoint:[10.0.1.204:39639,SSLRMIServerSocketFactory(host=ip-10-0-1-204.us-east-2.compute.internal/10.0.1.204, keyStoreLocation=rmi_keystore.jks, type=JKS, trustStoreLocation=rmi_keystore.jks, type=JKS, alias=rmi),SSLRMIClientSocketFactory(keyStoreLocation=rmi_keystore.jks, type=JKS, trustStoreLocation=rmi_keystore.jks, type=JKS, alias=rmi)](local),objID:[-40c4f57:17074c838d1:-7fff, 3321090150238356060]]]
```

But I can not connect to this container.

On Network information I can find next info:

**Private IP 10.0.1.204**

**Public IP 13.58.34.153**

But I can not connect to Public IP. How I can configure the network and connect to my ECS running container from my local PC?

(in **jmeter.properties** I setup **remote_hosts=13.58.34.153** )

Seems I have to get access to the internal IP **10.0.1.204** and redirect this on **13.58.34.153** but I'm not sure how I can do it, or maybe the problem is another.

Comment: can you provide ur security settings

Comment: You mean this: 

https://photos.app.goo.gl/m9zFUK9orYCGwJxc9

https://photos.app.goo.gl/m9zFUK9orYCGwJxc9

Comment: yeah, but not outbound traffic, inbound and specific to your instance

Comment: Inbound traffic selected to al and then could check this Public IP with curl 13.58.34.153:4000

But can not connect to this IP from Jmeter. Tried to use (jmeter.properties file) remote_hosts=13.58.34.153, 13.58.34.153:4000 and server_port=4000. But evrrytime got error no such object in table

Comment: Or when trying connect to public IP  - error :connection to: 10.0.1.52; nested exception is: 
 java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host (Host unreachable). Where  10.0.1.52 this is Private IP. That's mean I should allow someway access to port bu how?